# How do you override the default value of a field in a dexterity behavior in Plone?

Tags: plone, behavior, dexterity

We have a requirement for a dexterity content type to have exclude from navigation behaviour but for the `exclude_from_nav` field's default value to be `True`.  In the behaviour `plone.app.dexterity.behaviors.exclfromnav.IExcludeFromNavigation` it defaults to `False`.

Obviously I could create my own behaviour that copies `IExcludeFromNavigation` except for the default value but I was wondering if there was a way to do this based on reusing `IExcludeFromNavigation`.  We have other content types that use `IExcludeFromNavigation` where we do want it to default to `False`.

We're using Plone 4.1rc3 and Dexterity 1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this working using a `plone.directives.form` decorator.

I've added this to one of my behaviour modules.

```python
from plone.directives.form import default_value

@default_value(field = IExcludeFromNavigation['exclude_from_nav'])
def excludeFromNavDefaultValue(data):
    return data.request.URL.endswith('++add++my_item_type')
```

I also have the following in configure.zcml

```xml
<include package="plone.directives.form" file="meta.zcml" />
<include package="plone.directives.form" />

<grok:grok package="." />
```

Thanks to Martin for the large clue although his answer didn't quite solve my problem.  This feels like a bit of a hack to me - a more elegant solution would be nice.

Comment: Another option would be to register a custom add form and then use the 'form' (or is it 'view'?) discriminator to default_value() to specify an override for that form only.

Comment: Thanks, i used this for my scenario where i have two different object types in the same container i want to exclude by default. Problem was i couldnt put the same decorator on both object definitions or i would get config conflict complaints. I ended up just declaring on one of the types:: return data.request.URL.endswith('++add++my_item_type') or  data.request.URL.endswith('++add++my_other_type')

Comment: and like your example i had to remove the context parameter for it to work at all... seems hacky indeed.

Answer (score 5):

See http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/advanced/defaults and http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.directives.form#value-adapters, but basically:

```python
@form.default_value(field=IExcludeFromNavigation['exclude_from_nav'], context=IMyType)
def excludeFromNavDefaultValue(data):
    return True
```

Cheers,
Martin

Comment: Martin.  Thanks for your answer but it isn't quite what I'm after.  I may be wrong but `context` here seems to be the container to which you're adding the item and I need a rule based on the type of item being added.  I can see an ugly hack using a test of `data.request.URL` but something more elegant would be nice